# How to automate Selenium to click image button - find element by onclick? - Python

Tags: python, button, onclick, selenium-chromedriver, buttonclick

First post here because I couldn't find the answer to what I was looking for. I am trying to automate clicking the red button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn3iJ.jpg)

I automated the login to this site(can't say which one) and I added the wait function, but still, no matter whether I copy the full xpath, selector or other options that the copy function gives me inside "inspect element", I can't get Python to execute click the button.(might be because the button image serves as overlay - might be wrong but it looks to me like that).

This is the code I've used:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXXXXX\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("XXXXXXXXXXX")

driver.find_element_by_id("e_user").send_keys("XXXXXXXXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_id("e_pass").send_keys("XXXXXXXXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input").click()
time.sleep(5)
```

**driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick="btn_click(this,'btn_2_1')"]").click()`**

The bold command is not working. The rest is fine.

I tried find element by xpath, text name(početak prisustva na radu) and several other selenium find element by id options, but had no success.

I guess the best way would be to find the onclick element and click on it, but I am a newbie in code programming so if someone could help me out I would be really grateful. Each button you see there has a unique onlick name. I'll add a couple more pictures because they might be helpful to find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,
Djigzy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yPzR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use ActionChains
element is your element which you found with xpath

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
actions.click().perform()
```

You can read more about ActionChains here https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html